# Non size-regular pie chart parts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am creating pie chart with multiple data in one pie chart. In my case (don't know why) I have a problems with each series line height. My code looks that (http://jsfiddle.net/yATYL/):

```
$('#container2').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    center : [50, 50]
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Bla bla bla',
  },
  series: [
  {
    name: 'optionzz1',
    innerSize: '40%',
    startAngle: -120,
    data: [
    { 
        name: 'optionzz 1',
        y: 25,
        color: '#f26522'
    },{
        name: '',
        y: 75,
        color: 'white'
    }
    ]   
  },{
    name: 'optionzz2',
    innerSize: '60%',
    startAngle: -120,
    data: [
    { 
        name: 'optionzz 2',
        y: 15,
        color: '#2babe2'
    },{
        name: '',
        y: 85,
        color: 'white'
    }
    ]
  },{
    name: 'optionz3',
    innerSize: '80%',
    startAngle: -120,
    data: [
    { 
        name: 'optionzz 3',
        y: 60,
        color: '#bedbf3'

    },{
        name: '',
        y: 40,
        color: 'white'
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: I advice to try use each slice (point) as separated serie.

Comment: I've tried something with slice but effect was worse than this. Is it possible to set specific height to each serie and slice it with different values ?